# Server 2019 ADFS New Install Configuration Failing

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2019

I have been trying to setup a new ADFS server and the configuration is failing with the following error: The SSL certificate subject alternative names do not support host name 'certauth.sts.domain.com'. Configuring certificate authentication binding on port '49443' and hostname 'sts.domain.com'.

It ends with "The server is not operational."

I have reinstalled, disabled carbon black and checked the firewall but nothing has helped so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   You are encountering the error because the subject name and subject alternative name in the SSL certificate installed, should be the same as the federation service name that is set while configuring ADFS role on the server. Since, that certificate only contains ‘sts.domain.com’ as the federation service name which is ultimately the subject name defined on the certificate and does not contain ‘certificate.sts.domain.com’ as a subject alternative name, thus, due to which you are encountering this error. Please find the below screenshot of the ADFS post-install configuration for your reference: -

[image: ADFS role post-install configuration certificate install]

[image: Certificate signing request properties with subject alternative name to be configured]

•   As in Windows Server 2019, the ADFS setup by default installs ADFS role on port 443 using the same certificate with SAN (subject alternative name) on different hosts. Thus, you need to update your certificate to support SAN and configure it accordingly. Please find the below command to update certificate SAN binding on the same port, i.e., 443 with different hosts: -

```
  ‘ Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding -Member ADFS1.contoso.com -Thumbprint 
 '<thumbprint of cert>' ‘ --> change the name of the adfs server and insert the 
  thumbprint of the certificate installed.
```

•   Also, check the service account that is used for the ADFS service to connect with the database used for ADFS setup configuration and synchronization.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-support-for-alternate-hostname-binding-for-certificate-authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-user-certificate-authentication

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I am investigating.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  After hitting "Configure" it fails with "The server is not operational".  Also the set command failed.  Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding : Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:1500/policy. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 
00:00:02.0049602. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1500.

Comment: Please try adding the IP address to DNS binding entry in the hosts file for the adfs service name and its issued SSL certificate in the new ADFS server. Hopefully, this resolves it.

Comment: That did not seem to help either.  I am still working at it.  Does it matter that I am getting my SSL certificates from a third party CA?  I see it talking about AD CS.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter whether you get your SSL certificate from a third party CA or not, its absolutely fine, but it should include the alternative names other than the federation service name or the subject name that you are going to use as shown above in my answer. Also, you can check in server's event viewer and the server manager dashboard for any errors and events that might help to get to the root of the issue.

Comment: I created a self-signed certificate making sure the subject alternate names were correct.  I no longer get the ("error: The SSL certificate subject alternative names do not support host name 'certauth.sts.domain.com'. Configuring certificate authentication binding on port '49443' and hostname 'sts.domain.com'.) error.  I only get a message saying "The server is not operational".  I will check the logs again to see what I can find.

Comment: I was looking in another thread and saw someone having a similar issue because the server could not reach the PDC.  My server currently cannot reach the PDC.  I am having ports opened and will provide an update in a couple of days.

Comment: Yes, sure. Also, please check port 53 and 389 for internal DNS resolution of ADFS service name.

Comment: That resolved my issue.  Once connectivity to the PDC was opened I received the message "This server was successfully configured".  Thank you for your help.